# drawRect UIBezierPath performance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on the drawing app where user can select tool and by moving the finger on the screen the shape is drawing, like most of this kind of apps.

All of the drawings happened in `drawRect:` method in `UIView` subclass:

```
for (UIBezierPath p in [self.paths copy]) {
        [p stroke];
}
```

Of course i get the context and I use CGContextSaveGState and restore but roughly this is how it works.

There is `NSMutableArray` where `UIBezierPath` is added every time user release finger off the screen and `setNeedsDisplay` is invoked:

```
[self.myView.paths addObject:bezierpath];
[self.myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Everything is working fine but if the user keep drawing, for a while, the array contain a lot of `UIBeazierPaths` and at some point the drawing process start working slower and slower.

I know that `drawRect:` method is very expensive but I couldn't figure out the better way for doing this.

My question is how can I improve the performance? Do you know any other way to make it works more efficient?

For now I'm thinking about calculate the smallest rectangle which contain the bezier path and once user add new item I can call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` instead of `setNeedsDisplay` but I don't know is it good solution, any thoughts are more than welcome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't save an array of bezier paths. Once a path is complete, save the contents of the view as an image. Overlay further path strokes over this image. Drawing images is faster than drawing a hundred paths.

Comment: @duci9y the problem with image is that I cannot do undo/redo. But if I have a array of bezier paths I can undo all of the drawings and I can redo it as well.

Comment: Have an array of images instead? Loss on the memory side, gain on the performance side.